# What does "File has no header" build warning in visual studio mean

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm building my project fine but two of the files in my unit test project give a build warning "File has no header." they're unrelated and otherwise unremarkable .cs files.  I've googled but get swamped with results for 
"SA1633: The file has no header, the header Xml is invalid, or the header is not ...."

These warnings do not have an error code, what could they mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That´s a StyleCop code analysis violation.

This means that a C# source file is missing a file header.

The file header must begin on the first line of the file and must be formatted as a block of comments containing Xml, as follows:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="NameOfFile.cs" company="CompanyName">
//     Company copyright tag.
// </copyright>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. It wasn't the most informative warning, I didn't know stylecop was turned on in this project.

Comment: Can this be autogenerated somehow?

Comment: StyleCop will generate a separate warning if the file header does not contain the copyright tag `<copyright> ... </copyright>`.

Answer (score 1):

Add to header:

```
// <auto-generated />
```

A file that is completely auto-generated by a tool, and which should not be checked or enforced by StyleCop, can include an “auto-generated” header rather than the standard file header. This will cause StyleCop to ignore the file. This type of header should never be placed on top of a manually written code file.